# Background check with a BB bank

Tags: resume, job-offer, background-check

I recently got an offer to work as a summer analyst with an investment bank. I applied for this role back in July last year. Back then, I was working with lets say organisation B (under the company A) - I only mentioned the organisation B without mentioning the company A in my CV, but a simple google search will yield that organisation B is hosted by company A. I also have an employment letter under company A and it also mentions organisation B in it. To put a better context, say the employer is a university and the organization is a research center.

I will undergo background check soon but I have not received any detail yet. Would there be any issue for my condition mentioned above? How should I tell the HR about this?

Comment: Does your résumé accurately reflect your legal employer at all times?

Comment: Maybe good reading: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/97469/legally-speaking-who-is-the-employer-is-it-whoever-is-paying-the-employee-tell

Comment: Did you fill out your job application/reference check application yet? This is the document that's used for your background check. You need to explain what happened there.

Comment: To put a better context, say the employer is a university and the organization is a research center.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I wait until the new company reach out to me for the background check

Yes, it's better to deal with issues that are pointed out, then try and deal with everything and create a bit of drama that may not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For this answer I am assuming that the CV is essentially equivalent to a United Sates resume.

> I will undergo background check soon but I have not received any
> detail yet. Would there be any issue for my condition mentioned above?

There will be forms to fill out related to the background check. Resumes don't have to include every job. It is expected that more jobs will be listed on the background check forms. They frequently want to see zero gaps. So if there are periods of unemployment they want those gaps noted.

> Back then, I was working with lets say organisation B (under the company A).

Many people want to list the most recognizable or prestigious name. This can lead to issues if there is no way to prove the employment with organization B.

If the parent company is the one that has your employment information, then that is the one that will be providing dates of employment, job title and the like. So you will have to list them as your employer.

> Should I wait until the new company reach out to me for the background
> check (they use 3rd party vendor for this) to inform them about my
> employment status? How should I tell the HR about this?

There is no reason to update the info in a resume or CV, unless the company asks for it during the hiring process.

There is no reason to  do anything now, except making sure you have the contact information for your previous employers so that when you get the background checks forms you can complete them quickly.

Comment: They might not want your letter. They want to contact the employers independently.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I tell the HR about this?

I would suggest that you contact the recruiter or HR via email to ask them what they think you should do.

If the recruiter suggests that you send them an updated resume now, then do so now because it will take only 30 seconds to do the update. This updated resume will probably save HR from having some surprise about your resume, and save you some time waiting for them to ask you about the discrepancy, etc...

You may be OK either way in the end (i.e, having the old resume vs updated resume).

But, if the recruiter suggests that you make the correction early and send them a new version of the resume, then it is best to do so.

Answer (score 1):

First, clean up your employment history. You were only employed by ONE legal entity. This legal entity is the one who's name, address and ID is on all your paperwork (contract, paycheck, tax documents, etc.). For example, in most countries every "official" employer has a tax ID which uniquely identifies them.

So if your tax documents say "Alphabet Inc.", then Alphabet is your employer. If it says "Google", then you work for Google. The legal & financial arrangements between the two are none of your concern.

Once you have that sorted out, compare that to what you put on your CV. If it doesn't match, correct it and sent an update to the company (which a short explanation of why you did it). If it matches, you are all set.

You DO want to sent any corrections proactively as soon as possible. Otherwise you run the risk that the reference check comes back with "we have no idea who that is" since your employee record is not in the reference's employee data base (but in that of the parent or child company).

Comment: While that is generally good advice, my experience with detached consultancy (i.e. on the consultany company's payroll but working for a client of the company) is that it makes more sense to list _who you worked for_, since the interview is about your work experience, not who paid your salary. That being said, I mention both just to clear up any confusion, but I wouldn't hold it against an applicant who lists who they worked for.

Comment: This is terrible advice. I once interviewed someone who listed his jobs at McDonalds as "John FranchiseHolder Ltd" rather than McDonalds. That was the legal entity that hired and paid him, but it was deceptive to list it that way and he told me when I asked that he did it because "people don't take working at McDonalds seriously."

Comment: @KateGregory - There is likely a middle ground in the shared advice; saying you worked for John Franchise Holder Ltd at one of their McDonald's stores is fine.  Saying you worked for John Franchise Holder Ltd, which implies you worked for the franchise company itself (yeah, those companies have employees also), is the other extreme.